# Dust - Looping through json data

Tags: jquery, json, dust.js

I’m extremely stuck here. I’m using dust as a template compiler but for whatever reason I’m only returning one value from my json it’s not looping through and returning everything. So all I’m getting is **“DWade”** any ideas on what’s going on? Dust newbie so code samples are really really helpful.

JSON:

```
{
 "locations": [
 {
  "userName": "MKelly",
  "hours":"9-5"
 },
 {
  "userName": "MReynolds",
  "hours":"10-2"
 },
 {
  "userName": "DWade",
  "hours":"9-9"
 }
 ]
}
```

Here’s my jQuery:

```
var compiled = dust.compile($('.dust-info').html(), "tmp_skill");
dust.loadSource(compiled);

    $.getJSON("/services/userInfo?" + userTypes, function(data) {      
      $.each( data.locations, function( key, val ) {
      dust.render("tmp_skill", val, function(err, out) {
      //HTML output
      $('.dust-info').html(out);
      });
    });
```

TEMPLATE:

```
<div class="dust-info">
   {userName}
   {hours}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never really used dust before, but hopefully I can help a bit.

Firstly, you are clearing everything within .dust-info by changing the innerHTML of .dust-info every time you pass through `$.each`

try this as a template

```
{#locations}
    <div class="dust-info">
        {userName} {hours}
    </div>
{:else}
    No Location
{/locations}
```

Try it out here http://akdubya.github.io/dustjs/ - paste the template in 1 and your template data into 3.

Don't forget that you need to compile your template first before using it.

You should be able to do this afterwards

```
dust.render("tmp_skill", data.locations, function(err, out) {
    //append generated output to body
    $(body).append(out);
})
```

This example simply appends the output to the body

Comment: thanks, what you sent seems to work but what's wrong with my code? When I try to add that to mine I'm still getting just one result.

Answer (score 0):

As your comments with andyw above, you got 1 result because in javascript code, you used this : $('.dust-info').html(out);
with .html(out): js will find tag with class 'dust-info', then loop with data.locations and still replace html of this tag, not append - or display as a list, so that's why you just see 1 result. andyw's answer is the best way for looping data and display data list in dust template.